# Haskell Powerset in Lexicographic Order

Tags: haskell, powerset

I want to write a powerset function in Haskell with the function declaration of:

```
powerset :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

However, I'm trying to make with a lexicographical ordering so that:

```
powerset [1,2,3] = [[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,3], [2], [2,3], [3]]
```

I've found other ways of doing the powerset, such as:

```
powerSet = filterM (const [True, False])
```

but nothing that provides the powerset in lexographic order.  Is there any way to write the powerset function to provide that or to sort the unsorted powerset into this ordering?

Comment: Cannot you compose [sortBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy)? Not the most efficient way probably, but should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You may do a right fold:

```
powerset :: Foldable t => t a -> [[a]]
powerset xs = []: foldr go [] xs
    where go x acc = [x]: fmap (x:) acc ++ acc
```

then:

```
\> powerset [1, 2]
[[],[1],[1,2],[2]]
\> powerset [1, 2, 3]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,3],[2],[2,3],[3]]
```

<sub>(edited answer to remove the call to `tail` function)</sub>

Comment: How well does this handle large results? If you ask for `head . last . powerset $ [1..25]`, how long does that take?

Comment: @dfeuer That question seems eminently answerable by you without any further work by the answer writer.

Comment: @DanielWagner, that would normally be true, but I'm away from my laptop till Monday evening at the earliest, and I'm terribly impatient.

Comment: @dfeuer It is faster than the `filterM` version.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielWagner!

Comment: @dfeuer this is pretty fast actually. considering that `[1..25]` has `2^25` subsets, this performs very well compared to say `maximum [1..2^25]`.